# Facing issue once i run my react-native app on android

Tags: android, react-native

Once i try to run my react native app on android then it shows me an following error 
i can run run the command : react-native run-android
Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug FAILED

Any one solve my problem i will be very thankfull to you

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this it might resolve your[Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27362)

precisely you just need to add this in android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig{
  .......
 multiDexEnabled true 
  }
}
```